# Make delegated methods private

Tags: ruby, delegates, activesupport

I am delegating a couple of methods and also want them all to be private.

```
class Walrus
  delegate :+, :to => :bubbles

  def bubbles
    0
  end
end
```

I could say `private :+`, but I would have to do that for each method. Is there a way to either return a list of delegated methods or have delegate create private methods?

Comment: This part is not clear: "I could say private :+, but then every method I delegate has to be immediately, explicitly made private". Why is that?

Comment: If I want to delegate 10 methods and have them all be private, I would have to do this: `delegate :method_1, :method_2, :method_3, :method_4, :method_5, :method_6, :method_7, :method_8, :method_9, :method_10, :to => :bubbles` then `private :method_1, :method_2, :method_3, :method_4, :method_5, :method_6, :method_7, :method_8, :method_9, :method_10`

Comment: Then, the way you wrote was misleading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Monkey patch `Module` to add a helper method, just like what `ActionSupport` pack does:

```rb
class Module
  def private_delegate *methods
    self.delegate *methods
    methods.each do |m|
      unless m.is_a? Hash
        private(m)
      end
    end
  end
end

# then
class Walrus
  private_delegate :+, :to => :bubbles

  def bubbles
    0
  end
end
```

Answer (score 60):

Because `delegate` returns a list of the symbols passed in you can chain the method calls like this:

```
private *delegate(:foo, :bar, :to => :baz)
```

Comment: No monkeypatching and splat power. This guy deserves a medal.

Comment: This also works with `Forwardable#def_delegators`: `private(*def_delegators(:delegatee, :foo, :bar))` https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html#method-i-def_delegators

Answer (score 4):

For those using Rails 6+, thanks to Tomas Valent now [you can pass the private option to make the delegated methods private](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/31944):

```
delegate :method, to: :object, private: true
```

Comment: I do know the question isn't Rails tagged.